# Не работает height="match_parent" из-за того, что layout имеет height="wrap_content"

Tags: android

У меня есть ConstraintLayout (назову его example_layout), имеющий `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`. Внутри несколько десятков кнопок, и он вполне ожидаемо масштабируется по ним.
Но нужно, чтобы одна из этих содержащихся внутри кнопок имела размеры, как у самого ConstraintLayout. Попытался так:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/example_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:insetTop="0dp"
    android:insetBottom="0dp"
    app:cornerRadius="25dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/example_layout"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/example_layout" />
```

Но тогда кнопка принимает ширину правильную, а высоту - нет. При этом, если у example_layout стоит фиксированная height, к примеру, `android:layout_height="700dp"`, всё работает нормально, проблемы возникают именно при `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Comment: Что значит "неправильная высота"? Попробуйте добавить в т.ч. привязку верха кнопки к верху родителя

Comment: @ЮрийСПб имел ввиду неправильный размер по высоте. Кнопка привязывается правильно (привязка есть), но вот высота у неё не как у layout, а лишь как у скругления самой кнопки (логично, она же меньше не может стать, чем диаметр скругления), т. е. минимально допустимый размер, а не как у example_layout (т. е. `match_parent`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для View внутри ConstraintLayout нужно использовать "0dp" вместо "match_parent"

Comment: Это в том случае, когда оба соответствующих края вью к чему-либо привязаны и размер может быть рассчитан по этим привязкам